# static Dataset shared on IIS

Tags: asp.net

i have a static DataSet in an asp.net application where i pull the data from an external data source, for a client input(say from a textbox), create a table with the same input name in the dataset, and save it in My dataset.

i have hosted my application on iis where my app pool identity is running on my credentials.

**when accessing application from Machine A**: i have give an input in the textbox say "Hello world" (for this input it will fetch the data create a table with the same input name.)

**when accessing application from machine b:** if i try to give the same input, it gives me an error saying the table with the name "Hello world" already exits.

points:
1) both the machines are running on my credentials.

**My Question**

i was just wondering whether this dataset is shared across all the instances of the web application opened on different machines?? is this expected or i am assuming wrong?

or is this just happening because the app pool is running on my identity?

can some one enlighten me on this type of problems, how to handle it.

Comment: You may want to investigate caching as an alternative to static datasets. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the static dataset as you said, in a layman term

> "public static members are available till the run of the application
>   and to entire application, no matter how many users accessing that
>   object"

So If you dont want to share a single object to all users, then follow the 3 step rule, create instance, use it and dispose it. See the example below

```
public DatatSet ds = new DatatSet();  // Create a new instance of the any class , here i am using Dataset

ds.Tables.Count();  // Your actual operation. Here your logic will go

ds=null; or ds.Dispose() // dispose or flag it for garbage collection
```

Comment: thanks for the instant reply amit. even if i create a instance of it, how would i make sure that the dataset is available through out the life of the application(until the user closes the app).because i may have to use the dataset data. for that purpose i have created a static dataset so that i can use it. up to my knowledge the dataset data gets cleared after a postback. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @RitheshBaradi can you show me some code.. Update your question